# How to extract parameters of type stringList in cdk?

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-ssm

I am trying to extract existing SSM parameters of stringList in my cdk app.

I can store a single value, but to avoid duplication of code I am trying to store 3 values in single variable and access them as array in the form `value[0]`

```js
        const stringValue = ssm.StringParameter.fromStringParameterAttributes(this, 'MyValue', 
    
        const stringValue2 = ssm.StringListParameter.fromStringListParameterName(this, 'myValue', '/dev/name')
    
        const ssmstringlistoutput = new cdk.CfnOutput(this, 'ssmoutput', {
          value: cdk.Fn.select(0, stringValue2.stringListValue),
          description: 'name of ssmlist',
          exportName: 'avatarsBucket',
        });
    
    
        // Chatbot Slack Notification Integration
        const bot = new chat.SlackChannelConfiguration(
          this,
          "sample-slack-notification",
          {
            slackChannelConfigurationName: 'my channel name', 
            slackWorkspaceId: 'stringValue2[0]',
            slackChannelId: 'stringValue[1]',
            notificationTopics: [topic],
          }
        );
      }
```

The output is for verification. It outputs the entire list as one string value, not just the extracted first element as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `StringListParameter.fromStringListParameterName`, create a [CfnParameter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.CfnParameter.html) construct. Pass the parameter name as the default value:

```js
const listParam = new cdk.CfnParameter(this, 'ListParam', {
  type: 'AWS::SSM::Parameter::Value<List<String>>',
  default: '/dev/name',
});
```

Then select an element when passing the value as prop inputs:

```js
slackWorkspaceId: cdk.Fn.select(0, listParam.valueAsList),
slackChannelId: cdk.Fn.select(1, listParam.valueAsList),
```

**What's going on?** `fromStringListParameterName` synthesises to a CloudFormation [dynamic reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/dynamic-references.html#dynamic-references-ssm) like `{{resolve:ssm:/dev/name}}`. And as you discovered, CloudFormation apparently [cannot apply a split](https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/cfn-lint/issues/2181) to dynamic references.

Comment: Thanks this worked. i have a question how does CfnParameter can access SSM Parameters?

Comment: @JatinMehrotra It's a native CloudFormation [integration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html#aws-specific-parameter-types).

Comment: do you want to take a look on this one https://stackoverflow.com/q/72877803/13126651